# Where yum_repository resource is defined?

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook, lwrp

Probably this would be an easier one for the experts.

I’m learning to write custom LWRP and hence trying to understand the one that is already written.. the `yum` cookbook. It can be found here: http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/yum

**Question:**
In above cookbook, where (which file/line) is the resource `yum_repository` is defined?

I had gone through every single line of this cookbook and ran various combinations of `grep` searching for this string, but nothing helped.

Could you help me understand where and how the `yum_reposiroty` resource is defined/coded in above cookbook.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I think I should have been more clear. I am trying to understand what makes `yum_repository` a valid resource name whereas `yum_spiderman` is not a valid resource name. In other words, the keyword **`yum_repository`** MUST have been defined somewhere in the cookbook. I know that there is a resource n provider named `repository`. However, my question is about **`yum_repository`** (NOTE: I want to know where does the `yum_` part in the resource name figure in ). OR may be my interpretation is wrong but the question remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A LWRP consists of two files, a "resource" (declaration) and "provider" (implementation):

1. https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/yum/blob/master/resources/repository.rb
2. https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/yum/blob/master/providers/repository.rb

Comment: I think I should have been more clear. I am trying to understand what makes `yum_repository` a valid resource name whereas `yum_spiderman` is not a valid resource name. In other words, the keyword **`yum_repository`** MUST have been defined somewhere in the cookbook. I know that there is a resource n provider named `repository`. However, my question is about **`yum_repository`** (NOTE: I want to know where does the `yum_` part in the resource name figure in ). OR may be my interpretation is wrong but the question remains the same.

Comment: Within the cookbook the resource and provider files are called "repository" which in turn leads to a LWRP called "yum_repository". If I copied the files into my cookbook called "helloworld", then the LWRP would be called "helloworld_repository. So in conclusion chef is prefixing the cookbook name in order to namespace the resultant resource.